# How can I move the Applications and Files & Folders lenses in the launcher?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, lenses

In the launcher there are two types of launcher items. The default ones in the bottom part of the launcher, such as the `Workspace Switcher`, `Applications` lens, `Files & Folders` lens and `Trash`, and the other normal launcher items in the upper part of the launcher, such as the browser that I've added.

It seems I can't mix the two types of launchers and change the position of the two groups.

Is there any way to change that behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way you can change that behavior.

The upper part is for custom user launcher items, basically shortcuts, the bottom part is for lenses, like the `Applications` and `Files & Folders` lenses which are installed by default and there is the `Trash` launcher items which is fixed at the very bottom of the launcher.

You can customize the position of every item in its group however.

Comment: thank you for the answer. is it going to change in the future?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be possible to be honest. I'm not really sure that it'd make that much sense.